# ng-repeat not printing anything

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following scenario:

```
app.controller('ResourceController', function($scope, $sce){
        var resourceData;
        $scope.data = '';
        $scope.loadResources = function(){
            $.get('controllers/getResources.php', function(result){
                console.log(result);
                resourceData = $.parseJSON(result);
                $scope.data = $sce.parseAsHtml(resourceData);
            });
        };
        $scope.loadResources();
    });
```

The controller abovemakes a request to the server so that it can load all the resources and post them on an html table.

Here is the result of the `console.log(result)`:

```
[{"ID":"123","NAME":"Proyector Epson CX2435","DESCRIPTION":"Proyector Epson comprado en 2009.","STATUS":"Active","STATUS_DESCRIPTION":"Can be reserved.","LOCATION":"Elementary"},{"ID":"456","NAME":"Rack con Televisor #1","DESCRIPTION":"Televisor Sharp Aquos con Laptop, armado en 2011.","STATUS":"Active","STATUS_DESCRIPTION":"Can be reserved.","LOCATION":"First Floor, High School"}]
```

It's a big JSON and the data is there, good.

In the HTML, this is what I'm doing:

```
<div class="container-fluid" ng-controller="ResourceController as resource">
   .....
      <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="resourceInfo in data">
                <td>{{resourceInfo.ID}}</td>
                <td>{{resourceInfo.NAME}}</td>
                <td>{{resourceInfo.DESCRIPTION}}</td>
                <td>{{resourceInfo.STATUS}}</td>
                <td>{{resourceInfo.STATUS_DESCRIPTION}}</td>
                <td>{{resourceInfo.LOCATION}}</td>
                <td>
                    <a class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete-prompt">Delete</a>
                    <button class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#update-form">Update</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

When I open the Chrome dev tools here is what appears in the spot where the repeat should be:

[image]

Which makes me think there is something wrong going on, but I can't honestly figure what.

### EDIT

I just changed my controller to the following:

```
app.controller('ResourceController', function($scope, $sce){
        $scope.data = '';
        $scope.loadResources = function(){
            $.get('controllers/getResources.php', function(result){
                console.log(result);
                $scope.data = $.parseJSON(result);
                console.log($scope.data);
                console.log($scope.data[0].ID);
            });
        };
        $scope.loadResources();
    });
```

The `console.log($scope.data[0].ID)` prints `'123'`. I don't understand this, I thought this was in JSON format because I do parse it as JSON, but when I try to print it on the HTML, it just doesn't get printed.

Comment: looks like the problem is `$scope.data` is no a data collection, it is an function

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/fg7S4/1/

Comment: Judging by your console log, your $scope.data is turned into an array.
Try defining it to the first index (assuming all of your possible output would be in that manner.

Comment: $scope.data is not an array, it's JSON.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I'm trying to do the same thing you do there, but it is still not printing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem:

This probably because you load the data using jQuery and not Angular. Since the data is loaded asynchronously, Angular does not know they are there, so it doesn't updare the view.

#### Solutions:

1. Use Angular methods as much as possible, so Angular automatically knows what's going on.
   In your case, the `$http` service and Angular's `fromJson()` method (`angular.fromJson(...)`) should do the job.
2. If must use non-Angular methods, you need to explicitly inform Angular that it needs to re-check, manually triggering a $digesr cycle:

   $.get('controllers/getResources.php', function (result) {
       ...
       $scope.data = $.parseJSON(result);
       $scope.$apply();
   });

...or better yet:

```
$.get('controllers/getResources.php', function (result) {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        ...
        $scope.data = $.parseJSON(result);
    });
});
```

Comment: Dude you're such a lifesaver. I didn't know I shouldn't use propper jQuery ajax requests, and instead, use angular. so just to be clear, can you explain a bit more how can I do the same thing ith the `$http` from angular? My only (poor) experience from angular is taking the course from codeschool. A begginers course which isn't that good. They don't explain nothing of what I just read on your answer.

Comment: Since Angular also parses JSON responses into objects for you (by default - you can change that of course), you probably just need to inject `$http` and use it like this: `$http.get('controllers/getResources.php').success(function (data) { $scope.data = data; }).error(function (rejection) { /* Handle the request error... */ });`

Comment: Interesting, I'll change it and give it a try. One more question. Does angular rely heavily on promises? I'm pretty new to deferred objects and dealing with promises.

Comment: @hsoto, yes, angular uses promises heavily.

Comment: Angular does not rely on promises. It supports it and uses it, but the question is how much will your app rely on promises. Promises is Angular's way to deal with async operations. If you want to support async operations you'll have to use promises.